# Making an advanced search filter on a text file

Tags: android, file, android-jetpack-compose, full-text-search

I am displaying text from a text file. Like this

[image: Displaying contents of file in text]

I want to create an advanced search filter like this. Where on clicking the particular block  it will scroll to that position of the file.

[image: Searched items]

I am using jetpack compose for the project. I have no clue how to achieve this.
When I try to display the whole string (read from the file) in a single scrollable textview,
it lags a lot on scrolling. I need an alternative solution and how to achieve this search.

In gist What I need is:

1. Display the content of file smoothly (As text files can be very big).
2. On entering any letter/word/phrase the search results should show the few words near them
   as well as displayed.
3. On clicking on any searched result the file will scroll to that particular position to
   show the searched query.